# EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist on EntityManager.remove

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a ContactEntity (parent) and PhoneNumberComponent (child) relationship.  When I try to EntityManager.remove() the child I get the Exception below.

Also, I noticed that if I remove the CascadeType.Persist or change FetchType.EAGER to LAZY in the phoneNumbers mapping in AbstractContactEntity my JUnit passes.

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Using:hibernate, hsqldb

### Stacktrace

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.bb.sc.contact.jpa.entity.PhoneNumberComponent#<null>]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1329)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1280)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1286)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:969)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy35.flush(Unknown Source)
    at test.bb.sc.contact.jpa.entity.PhoneNumberComponentJUnit.testCRUD(PhoneNumberComponentJUnit.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

### ContactEntity (parent)

```
@Entity
@Table (name="CONTACT")
@Inheritance (strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn (name="CONTACT_DISCRIMANATOR")
public abstract class AbstractContactEntity implements Auditable {
    @Column (name="CONTACT_ID", nullable=false)
    @Id @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="contact", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=PostalAddressComponent.class)
    private Collection<PostalAddressComponent> postalAddresses;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="contact", targetEntity=PhoneNumberComponent.class, cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<PhoneNumberComponent> phoneNumbers;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="contact", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=EmailAddressComponent.class)
    private Collection<EmailAddressComponent> emailAddresses;
    @Embedded
    private DbAudit dbAudit;
```

### ContactDetail (abstract child)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractContactDetail implements Auditable{
    @Id @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne @JoinColumn (name="CONTACT_TYPE_ID", nullable=false)
    private ContactDetailTypeEntity type;
    @ManyToOne (targetEntity=AbstractContactEntity.class) @JoinColumn (name="CONTACT_ID", nullable=false)
    private AbstractContactEntity contact;
    @Embedded
    private DbAudit dbAudit;
```

### ContactDetail impl (concrete impl child)

```
@Entity
@Table (name="PHONE_NUMBER")
@AttributeOverride (name="id", column=@Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER_ID"))
public class PhoneNumberComponent extends AbstractContactDetail {

    @Column (name="AREA_CODE", nullable=false)
    private Integer areaCode;
    @Column (name="PREFIX", nullable=false)
    private Integer prefix;
    @Column (name="SUFFIX", nullable=false)
    private Integer suffix;
    @Column (name="EXTENSION")
    private Integer ext;
```

### JUnit

```
@Before
public void setup () {
    contact = new ContactPersonEntity();
    type = new ContactDetailTypeEntity();

    type.setCode("CODE");
    type.setType("TYPE");
    em.persist(contact);
    em.persist(type);
    em.flush();

    // Before each test, make sure the EntityManager has a clean persistence context.
    em.clear();
}   
@Test
public void testDelete () {
    PhoneNumberComponent p = new PhoneNumberComponent(111, 222, 3333, 44, contact, type);
    em.persist(p);
    em.flush();
    assertNotNull (p.getId());

    em.clear();
    PhoneNumberComponent found = em.find(PhoneNumberComponent.class, p.getId());
    assertNotNull (found);
    em.remove(found);
    em.flush();
}
```

The JUnit bombs on the last em.flush you see in my JUnit.  Another observation is that if I replace the em.remove(foundUpd) line in my JUnit with the code below, the test passes.  However, I would prefer not having to load the parent object graph, traverse it, and explicitly break the parent-child link just to delete a record.  Thanks.

```
    AbstractContactEntity c = em.find(AbstractContactEntity.class, 1L);
    c.getPhoneNumbers();
    Iterator<PhoneNumberComponent> it = c.getPhoneNumbers().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        PhoneNumberComponent p = it.next();
        em.remove(p);
        it.remove();
    }
```

Comment: @user1143825 - from Hibernate's perspective, there is no problem.  I added an Edit to my answer to help clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an FetchType.EAGER mapping, loading the child in the persistence context will also load the parent.  In my JUnit I executed a EntityManager.clear before finding the child.  Thinking the child was the only entity in the persistence context was a poor assumption.

In debug, I executed

```
PhoneNumberComponent found = em.find(PhoneNumberComponent.class, p.getId());
```

and noticed a *pair* of SQLs it generated.

```
Hibernate: select phonenumbe0_.PHONE_NUMBER_ID as PHONE1_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT10_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as CREATE2_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.CREATE_USER as CREATE3_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as UPDATE4_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.UPDATE_USER as UPDATE5_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_DETAIL_TYPE_ID as CONTACT11_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.AREA_CODE as AREA6_3_2_, phonenumbe0_.EXTENSION as EXTENSION3_2_, phonenumbe0_.PREFIX as PREFIX3_2_, phonenumbe0_.SUFFIX as SUFFIX3_2_, abstractco1_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT2_0_0_, abstractco1_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as CREATE3_0_0_, abstractco1_.CREATE_USER as CREATE4_0_0_, abstractco1_.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as UPDATE5_0_0_, abstractco1_.UPDATE_USER as UPDATE6_0_0_, abstractco1_.ORGANIZATION_NAME as ORGANIZA7_0_0_, abstractco1_.FRIST_NAME as FRIST8_0_0_, abstractco1_.LAST_NAME as LAST9_0_0_, abstractco1_.CONTACT_DISCRIMANATOR as CONTACT1_0_0_, contactdet2_.CONTACT_DETIAL_TYPE_ID as CONTACT1_1_1_, contactdet2_.CODE as CODE1_1_, contactdet2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_1_1_, contactdet2_.TYPE as TYPE1_1_ from PHONE_NUMBER phonenumbe0_ inner join CONTACT abstractco1_ on phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_ID=abstractco1_.CONTACT_ID inner join CONTACT_TYPE contactdet2_ on phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_DETAIL_TYPE_ID=contactdet2_.CONTACT_DETIAL_TYPE_ID where phonenumbe0_.PHONE_NUMBER_ID=?
Hibernate: select phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT10_0_2_, phonenumbe0_.PHONE_NUMBER_ID as PHONE1_2_, phonenumbe0_.PHONE_NUMBER_ID as PHONE1_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_ID as CONTACT10_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as CREATE2_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.CREATE_USER as CREATE3_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as UPDATE4_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.UPDATE_USER as UPDATE5_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_DETAIL_TYPE_ID as CONTACT11_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.AREA_CODE as AREA6_3_1_, phonenumbe0_.EXTENSION as EXTENSION3_1_, phonenumbe0_.PREFIX as PREFIX3_1_, phonenumbe0_.SUFFIX as SUFFIX3_1_, contactdet1_.CONTACT_DETIAL_TYPE_ID as CONTACT1_1_0_, contactdet1_.CODE as CODE1_0_, contactdet1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT3_1_0_, contactdet1_.TYPE as TYPE1_0_ from PHONE_NUMBER phonenumbe0_ inner join CONTACT_TYPE contactdet1_ on phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_DETAIL_TYPE_ID=contactdet1_.CONTACT_DETIAL_TYPE_ID where phonenumbe0_.CONTACT_ID=?
```

Then I added the following line and noticed no SQL in the console.  No DB action was needed because the EntityManager was able to find the parent in the persistence context.

```
AbstractContactEntity c = em.find(AbstractContactEntity.class, 1L);
```

If I change my phoneNumbers mapping in AbstractContactEntity to FetchType.LAZY I only get the 1st SQL.

### Edit

I don't know [why Hibernate does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065974/why-does-hibernate-load-the-parent-entity-when-finding-a-child-in-fetchtype-eage), but for now I'm just accepting the behavior and designing accordingly.

Here's an illustration of what's probably going on in Hibernate.

When I find() my child entity, the parent is also loaded in the persistence context.  Then the remove() marks a delete instruction to the child and an update instruction to the parent.  Finally, when I flush(), the child is deleted and the parent is pushed back to the DB.  But since that parent still has a reference to the deleted child I get kicked with EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist.

Comment: So it seems that deleting a child from an EAGER fetch needs it's association explicitly removed (removed from parent's collection).  I should look into orphanRemoval=true.

Answer (score 0):

ContactEntity (parent) and PhoneNumberComponent (child)

You have list of PhoneNumberComponent in ContactEntity. To delete child follow these steps:

1. get PhoneNumberComponent  from DB.
2. get respective  ContactEntity from DB.
3. remove respective PhoneNumberComponent from ContactEntity list.
4. now delete PhoneNumberComponent