# Why does Hibernate load the parent entity when finding a child in FetchType.Eager mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Using: Hibernate 4

In a parent-child relationship where there's a FetchType.Eager mapping, I noticed that Hibernate will load the parent entity any time and EntityManager.find is performed on a child.    This seems a bit wasteful.  The "behind the scene" loading of the parent is resulting in an extra SELECT and extra object in the persistence context.  Also, it [forces the app to address the parent-child association when removing a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058085/entitynotfoundexception-deleted-entity-passed-to-persist-on-entitymanager-remov).

Why does Hibernate behave this way?  Is this mandated by the JPA spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from the specification that persistent attribute with eager fetch strategy must be fetched when entity is loaded:

> An entity is considered to be loaded if all attributes with
>   FetchType.EAGER—whether explictly specified or by default—(including
>   relationship and other collection-valued attributes) have been loaded
>   from the database or assigned by the application. Attributes with
>   FetchType.LAZY may or may not have been loaded.